Possibility and Options for customizing the PlanningCalendar in UI5
I'm working with UI5 Tooling and need to customize the PlanningCalendar control to use in an Angular app. Specifically, I want to:

Add extra headers/columns to the table.
Implement expandable rows within the table.

Is this possible, or is customization limited to basic UI elements like buttons? I've searched the API reference but haven't found a clear way to achieve this functionality.
If it is possible:

Can these changes be done with UI5 Tooling, or should I look into other approaches (e.g., UI5 SDK)?
Are there any examples or documentation to help guide this?
Should I extend the control or create a custom one?

If the above options aren't suitable, what else can I try to achieve this functionality?
